# Delphi and Internet Explorer, create "global" IE

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, ole

I have some inherited code for opening IE, this is short version :

```
procedure OpenIE(URL: OleVariant; FieldValues: string = '');
var ie : IWebBrowser2;
begin
  ie := CreateOleObject('InternetExplorer.Application') as IWebBrowser2;
  ie.Navigate2(URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers);
  ShowWindow(ie.HWND, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
  ie.Visible := true;
  ...
end;
```

Since CreateOleObject takes a long time to execute I would like to have one "prepared" IE for the first run.

For example in Main FormCreate to call CreateOleObject, then for 1st call of OpenIE to use "IE" object already created.

For 2nd, 3rd ... call of OpenIE - just usual call
    ie := CreateOleObject

When I try to code it, I get some threads and marshaling errors, I am newbie in this area. What would be proper way to do this (some small code example would be great) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean you're trying to use OLE in multithread environment? can you give the error messages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you are creating the browser instance in a different thread from which you then issue subsequent calls. The following trivial code works exactly as expected:

```
type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
    ShowBrowser: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ShowBrowserClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FBrowser: Variant;
  end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FBrowser := CreateOleObject('InternetExplorer.Application');
end;

procedure TMainForm.ShowBrowserClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FBrowser.Navigate('http://stackoverflow.com');
  ShowWindow(FBrowser.HWND, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
  FBrowser.Visible := True;
end;
```

I'm not using `IWebBrowser2` because I don't have the import unit handy. But that won't change anything – your problems will not be related to early/late binding.

Obviously `FormCreate` runs in the GUI thread. And `ShowBrowserClick` is a button `OnClick` event handler. And so it runs in the main GUI thread.

If you are calling your `OpenIE` function from a thread other than the GUI thread, that would explain your errors. If you access the browser on a thread other than the one on which it was created, you will receive an `EOleSysError` with message *The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread*.

Finally, a word of advice when asking questions. If you receive an error message, make sure you include that exact error message in your question. Doing so makes it much more likely we can provide good answers.

Comment: Thanks sybond, David,

Yes, code works thanks, but in my app I get :

raised exception class EOleSysError with message 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread'.

I think it's different thread, I'm not sure, it looks like this:
IEUnit has functions for LoadIE and OpenIE

LoadIE is called from MainFormCreate, OpenIE is called from completely different unit, I guess from separate thread.

Hope this info helps, thanks

Comment: @Milan You should put that error message in the question rather than a comment. So, I think you know how to solve your problem now. Right?

Comment: You're right, I just added a comment and pasted the error message. These threads are confusing me, I apologize.