# Delphi accessing OleObject from 2 different threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, ole

I have some inherited code for opening IE and I have some troubles, here is what I have:

IEUnit.pas (no form) has routines for LoadIE and OpenIE

OpenIE is called from separate thread and it looks like this

```
procedure OpenIE(URL: OleVariant; FieldValues: string = '');
var ie : IWebBrowser2; // <-- This should become "global" variable for the IEUnit
begin
  ie := CreateOleObject('InternetExplorer.Application') as IWebBrowser2;
  ie.Navigate2(URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers);
  ShowWindow(ie.HWND, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
  ie.Visible := true;
  ...
end;
```

I would like to have "global" ie variable in the unit and to write LoadIE routine like this :

LoadIE should be called from FormCreate (main thread)

It should just create "global" ie object

```
  ie := CreateOleObject('InternetExplorer.Application') as IWebBrowser2;
```

so the OpenIE function doesn't need to create it, just to use it (purpose is to speed things up)

So problem is how to access same OLE object from 2 different threads, one creates the object, the other one uses it.

---

When I write code that doesn't take care of threads I get an error

exception class EOleSysError with message 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread'

How should I do it, to take care of threads (I'm not experienced with threads, some reading and video links are welcome).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, because it was the subject of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817277/delphi-and-internet-explorer-create-global-ie), you need all calls to the COM object to be made from the same thread. The obvious choice is the main GUI thread. So, create the `IWebBrowser2` in your main form's `OnCreate` event handler. And then use `TThread.Synchronize` or `TThread.Queue` whenever you need to show the browser. The code that you pass to `Synchronize` or `Queue` will be executed on the main GUI thread.

Assuming you are using a modern version of Delphi with support for anonymous methods you'd write it like this:

```
procedure TMyThread.ShowBrowser(const URL: string);
var
  Proc: TThreadProcedure;
begin
  Proc := procedure
    begin
      MainForm.Browser.Navigate2(URL, ...);
      ShowWindow(MainForm.Browser.HWND, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
      MainForm.Browser.Visible := true;
    end;
  Queue(Proc);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you all, I'll probably try to find a way to do it from the same thread

Answer (score 6):

[MTA model](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/150777/EN-US) COM servers can only be used from within their associated apartment. Here's the [explanation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172314) of the error with the following advice:

> The correct way of transferring an interface pointer (either a direct
>   pointer or a proxy pointer) from one apartment to another is via COM's
>   marshaling mechanism. The source apartment can call
>   [CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to marshal the interface
>   pointer to a shared (global) stream. The destination apartment can
>   unmarshal this interface pointer by calling
>   [CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Are you recommending that Milan uses `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream()` and `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream()`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No, since there's not enough information to recommend anything. I'm only pointing out the documented way to access COM objects from different threads if and when it's needed (which might be the case here as the question suggests).

Comment: Hmm, I think it's safe enough to recommend only calling the COM object from a single thread.

Comment: Sure, but safe enough might not be good enough. (Safe but slow, for example.)

Comment: Why would it be slow? I can't see any performance problems here.

Comment: For example, serializing execution into one thread when some tasks might be performed concurrently in separate threads might be relatively slow.

Comment: You can mitigate that by using an asynchronous model, e.g. `TThread.Queue`.

Answer (score 2):

Non-free-threaded COM objects can only be used by/on/in the same thread as the one it's created for/on/in/with. In your case, to speed things up, I would use a plain global `treadvar` value of type IWebBrowser2, or a property in your class overriding TThread.

Answer (score 1):

use CriticalSection to wrap all calls to the OleObject. also use Synchronize to call from the "other" thread to the main UI thread (this is why you get the exception).

Comment: Why would you need to use a critical section once you ensure that all access to the COM object is from the same thread?

Comment: if all access to the object is from the same thread, you are right, you do not need to use CriticalSection...